# how to copy from text file to struct using fscanf

Tags: c, list, text, scanf

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>



typedef struct Student{
char nume[30];
char prenume[30];
float medie;
}Student;

int main()
{   FILE *st= fopen("input.txt","r");
    Student a[10];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<10;i++)
        fscanf(st,"%s %s %f",a[i].nume,a[i].prenume,a[i].medie);
    fclose(st);
    return 0;
}
```

this should read the first name, last name and a number from a list, why does it crash?

the list looks like this:

```
ALEXANDRU Tudor 2.23
AMUZA Marius 2.15
CELCAN Alexandra 2.29
KONRAD Eric 2.15
...
```

Comment: `fscanf` wants the address of the variable (not his value), change `a[i].medie` to `&a[i].medie` for the `float` member.

Comment: What are the return values of `fopen()` and `fscanf()`? Whenever you use functions like these and ignore the return values, you will very likely be asked the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Almost certainly because you are passing a[i].medie (the value of the float) not &a[i].medie (the address of the float) to fscanf().

But you will also crash if the file input.txt is not present or not readable, as you don't check for an error return from fopen()